# how to draw lines on a picture background in pygame

Tags: python, drawing, pygame

I would like to draw lines (of arbitrary position and length) onto a surface in pygame, which itself is an image loaded from a file on disk.

Can anyone point me to some example code that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for:

```
# load the image
image = pygame.image.load("some_image.png")

# draw a yellow line on the image
pygame.draw.line(image, (255, 255, 0), (0, 0), (100, 100))
```

Typically you don't draw to the original image, since you'll have to reload the image to get the original back (or create a copy of it before you start drawing onto it). Perhaps what you actually need is something more like this:

```
# initialize pygame and screen
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 576))

# Draw the image to the screen
screen.blit(image, (0, 0))

# Draw a line on top of the image on the screen
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0), (50, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Help on module pygame.draw in pygame:

NAME
    pygame.draw - pygame module for drawing shapes

FILE
    d:\program files\python25\lib\site-packages\pygame\draw.pyd

FUNCTIONS
    aaline(...)
        pygame.draw.aaline(Surface, color, startpos, endpos, blend=1): return Rect
        draw fine antialiased lines

```
aalines(...)
    pygame.draw.aalines(Surface, color, closed, pointlist, blend=1): return Rect

arc(...)
    pygame.draw.arc(Surface, color, Rect, start_angle, stop_angle, width=1): return Rect
    draw a partial section of an ellipse

circle(...)
    pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0): return Rect
    draw a circle around a point

ellipse(...)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(Surface, color, Rect, width=0): return Rect
    draw a round shape inside a rectangle

line(...)
    pygame.draw.line(Surface, color, start_pos, end_pos, width=1): return Rect
    draw a straight line segment

lines(...)
    pygame.draw.lines(Surface, color, closed, pointlist, width=1): return Rect
    draw multiple contiguous line segments

polygon(...)
    pygame.draw.polygon(Surface, color, pointlist, width=0): return Rect
    draw a shape with any number of sides

rect(...)
    pygame.draw.rect(Surface, color, Rect, width=0): return Rect
    draw a rectangle shape
```